# Windows Forms Development - Books

Tags: .net, winforms

So I'm reading a book for architecting applications for the enterprise from the Microsoft Press. It's a great book, and I'm learning a lot. However, it's very high level, and can be applied to a lot of different domains (not even just .NET, even though that's how the book is geared).

The first project I want to develop after reading the book is a Windows Forms application in .NET 4.0. I want to use a lot of the books concepts to develop the app, but I really want a great Windows Forms dedicated book to read before starting that's really going to tell me all I need to know about developing Windows Forms apps.

I found plenty of books for .NET 2.0 and stuff, but nothing for Windows Forms in the new .NET 4.0 Framework.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may find your 2.0 book to be adequate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696932/anything-new-for-winforms-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 3):

The biggest reason it's hard to find books on Forms development in .NET 4.0 is that Microsoft is abandoning WinForms for WPF.  Although WinForms will continue to work in the near future, it will not be improved on.  If it's possible, I would suggest to move to WPF.  If not, books on Winforms in .NET 2.0 and 3.5 should be sufficient.

Comment: I guess I could give WPF a try. It would also serve as a good connection into Silverlight.